# How to display XML tags in browser after merging XML files using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got a few XML files that I've managed to combine using an xsl code snippet, the normal xml files show the XML structure in the browser, but this merged .XML file displays the XML content as plain text. **Why does it do this?**

**So my question is:** How do I make it so I can see the XML structure of this merged xml file? I'd like to be able to open and collapse the nodes just like I can with the ''normal'' xml files in my browser.

Here's my .xsl file that merges the files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<xsl:transform
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/book">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="document('file1.xml')" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="document('file2.xml')" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="document('file3.xml')" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you run that transformation in the browser as well (i.e. with a `<?xml-stylesheet ...?` pi in an input XML)? I think most browsers in that case expect you to use XSLT to transform the XML into something like (X)HTML, SVG the browsers know to render and display (or at least style the resulting XML with CSS), only some versions of Opera in the past did what you wish, e.e. if the XML is some unknown format render its source as a collapsible tree. So unless you do the XSLT transformation outside of the browser I don't think you will get the desired behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, i've got the <?xml-stylesheet ...? line in my book.xml which shows the XML files combined.